# Use featureimage in gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I want to display featuredImages within my blog-posts.

My frontmatter looks like this:

```
---
title: My pst with a feature image
date: "2021-05-16T09:45:00.000Z"
description: "Some cool post with a feature image"
tags: [demo]
featuredImage: "feature.png"
---
```

The index.md and the feature.png are siblings in the same directory. I'm using this query:

```
query BlogPostBySlugDev($id: String!) {
  markdownRemark(id: {eq: $id}) {
    id
    frontmatter {
      title
      date(formatString: "D. MMMM YYYY", locale: "de-DE")
      dateIso: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD", locale: "en-US")
      description
      tags
      featuredImage {
        childImageSharp {
          gatsbyImageData(width: 400)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm getting this result in the GraphiQL:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "markdownRemark": {
      "id": "f73a3644-493c-5cc4-8a5d-f749db898954",
      "frontmatter": {
        "title": "My pst with a feature image",
        "date": "16. Mai 2021",
        "dateIso": "2021-05-16",
        "description": "Some cool post with a feature image",
        "tags": [
          "demo"
        ],
        "featuredImage": {
          "childImageSharp": null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

This is not what I expected. I would have expected to get my image-data here ... likewise I'm getting this message on the console (running gatsby in development mode):

```
warn You can't use childImageSharp together with undefined.undefined — use publicURL instead. The childImageSharp portion of the query in this file will return null:
undefined
```

I'm using these packages:

```json
    "gatsby": "^3.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^2.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-pnpm": "^1.2.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^4.1.0",
    "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^3.1.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.1.0",
```

I also extended the `Frontmatter` type in my `gatsby-node.js`, so that featureImage would be recognized as a file:

```json
    type Frontmatter {
      title: String
      description: String
      date: Date @dateformat
      tags: [String!]
      featuredImage: File
    }
```

And finally I setup the `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin to resolve two paths (as I have posts and pages):

```json
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
        name: `blog`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    }
```

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> The `index.md` and the `feature.png` are siblings in the same directory.

But your `gatsby-source-filesystem` shows two different folders:

> ```
> {
>   resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
>   options: {
>     path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
>     name: `blog`,
>   },
> },
> {
>   resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
>   options: {
>     name: `images`,
>     path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
>   },
> }
> ```

It seems that Gatsby is not able to create the proper nodes for your image because it's not able to find it in your filesystem.

I would suggest following your `gatsby-source-filesystem` approach, so, one folder for the posts (markdowns) and one folder for the images. Both folders can be siblings of course but then, your markdown structure should look like:

```
---
title: My pst with a feature image
date: "2021-05-16T09:45:00.000Z"
description: "Some cool post with a feature image"
tags: [demo]
featuredImage: "../feature.png"
---
```

Comment: Well acutally my post is located at `~/content/blog/2021/05/featuretest`. Here are `index.md` as well als `feature.png`. The `~/src/images` is used for static images I reference from pages, not blog-posts. Since the posts itself are "discoverd" I would have assumed, that the images next to the `index.md` would be discoverd as well.

Especially looking at https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/#configuring-for-images-and-posts-in-the-same-directory I would have assumed, that this approach should work.

Comment: Of course, if you want to use the image as "raw" you can place it in the same folder (since it's the reference) but as you can see in https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/#querying-for-images-from-frontmatter the image is relative to the blog folder (inside /images). This, plus the filesystem, allows Gatsby to create the proper nodes. To fix your issues, you will need to place markdown images in `/images` folder. This will allow you to query images using GraphQL nodes.

Comment: Ok - let my try to get this right ... so this is my current folder structure:

`/content/blog/2021/05/featureset/index.md` & `/content/blog/2021/05/featureset/feature.png`

So you suggest, I should move my `feature.png` from the `featuretest` folder to `/src/images/feature.png`. I guess I would have to update my frontmatter in the `index.md` from `featuredImage: "feature.png"` to `featuredImage: "../../../../../src/images/feature.png"` in order to point to the right folder, relative to my `index.md`.

But I still don't get any "result" from my graphql-query :(

Comment: Well, what I'm saying is that your `.md` folder should not contain any other assets rather than markdowns. In addition, to allow Gatsby to create GraphQL nodes for your assets (the one you are missing in `childImageSharp` you need to let Gatsby know where those assets are located (via filesystem). You can put the image in the same folder than the markdown but then, you won't be able to query it via GraphQL, you will be able to take a string and use it as `src` of a standard `<img>` tag. The structure you choose should be consistent with the filesystem set.

Comment: Ok - so I moved the `feature.png` to the images folder, and updated the "path" in the frontmatter (see above) - but still I don't get any data in the GraphQL query.

Comment: If in your `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground you can create any query to fetch your `feature.png` (within any node) the issue is your markdown path (something related with the relativity of the paths)